# Editing multiple tables with python-docx

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

I have an existing docx file where I am trying to update certain cells on multiple tables using python-docx.

The document looks something like

| Author | $Author | Creation Date | $Creation_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

|  | Name | Reviewed Date | Version |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Reviewer | $Reviewer | $Reviewed_Date | $Version |
|  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |

| Name of Leaver | $Name_of_leaver | Leaving Date | $Leaving_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

| merged cell | Laptop + Charger | $Serial_Number | checkbox |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| merged cell | iPhone + Charger | $Serial_Number | checkbox |
| merged cell | iPad | $Serial_Number | checkbox |
| merged cell | Monitor | $Serial_Number | checkbox |
| merged cell | Printer | $Serial_Number | checkbox |

I have been successfully able to edit the first, second or third tables using code like

```
details_table = document.tables[2]
#Name of Leaver Cell
details_table.cell(0, 1).text = 'Joe Blogs'
#Leaving Date Cell
details_table.cell(0,3).text = '1973-10-17'
```

This updates the $Name_of_leaver and $Leaving_Date cells as I would expect. I have identfied table 3 with `document.tables[2]` counting from 0 and then identified the rows with `details_table.cell(x, y)` where x and y are the rows and columns respectivley, again counting from 0.

However, when I then try to edit the 4th table in a similar fashion, things start to go wrong:

```
hardware_table = document.tables[3]
#Laptop Serial Number 
hardware_table.cell(0,2).text = 'test value'
```

I would expect this code to update the row 1, column 3 and replace "$Serial_Number" with "test value", but instead I just get an error:

> Exception has occurred: IndexError.
> list index out of range

The only thing I can think of is is the merged cells are somehow mucking things up for me but I am not sure how to resolve this.

How can I account for merged cells with my code?

If it isn't merged cells causing the problem, what is?

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.